# Ionic View doesn't show on chrome inspect

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools, motorola

### The problem

I'm trying to do some debugging on my ionic app and I have a [Moto Maxx](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_maxx-6779.php) (international version of the [Droid Turbo](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_droid_turbo-6727.php)). Problem is, the device is detected, but my application is not listed on `chrome://inspect`, as you can see on the screenshot below.

[image: Motorola error]

**P.S.:** Other devices show my app just fine. And **the problem also happened with other motorola devices**.

### What have I done so far

- Enabled USB debugging. (And adb see the phone just fine).
- The device is well connected, tested with other cables.
- `Discover USB devices` is checked on `chrome://inspect`.
- Tried to close and open the app before and after USB connection.

---

So, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change to **USB Mode** to **MTP** or **PTP(Linux)** from **Charge Only** for it to work

Comment: np it was a pleasure :D

Answer (score 1):

You should install the device's driver. I had also issue but with Samsung.